# How to execute CGI code instead of displaying it

Tags: python, apache, cgi

My CGI scripts (written in python) seem to only display the code. I've followed essentially every tutorial online for CGI and read all the trouble shooting articles but to no avail. I have tried downloading other files to make sure it wasn't my code that was causing the issue).

I've added the handler in `apache2.conf` and have tried putting files in both `/var/www/html` and `/var/etc/cgi-bin`. The files in `/var/www/html` just display the code and `/var/etc/cgi-bin` just says `File not found`.
I have also made sure to add executable permissions with `chmod 755 <filename>`, but that didn't work either.
I have also made sure to have appropriate import statements and the `#!` statement.

Any ideas on how I could fix this?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10124235/py-file-showing-code-in-browser-instead-of-running

Comment: Add code formatting

Comment: For people to be able to help you with your question, you should post the contents of  your `apache2.conf` and a code example, otherwise it's near impossible to figure out what the problem is.